# Converting a list of frequencies back to original value

Tags: python

I'm working on making a function that returns the highest value in a list.

This is a sequence of tasks, so first I made a function to roll a set amount of d6 dice, like roll(n) for instance. Then I made a new function to figure out which number was rolled most frequently, which gave me a list looking like this: [0, 1, 0, 3, 1, 0]. Now my issue is to make a function that finds the most frequent element in that list.

So far I've made this piece of code:

```
def find_most(amount):
    most = 0 
    for I in amount:
        if I > most:
            most = I

    return most
```

So my issue now is finding a way to convert that number given, back to a dice roll. Currently it will just give out the number 3 since it's the highest number in my example list, but I want it to give me the number 4, since the list shows that I rolled a 4, 3 times when rolling 5 dice.

I tried using indexing and another if - elif thing, but it won't give me the right number.

Comment: `collections.Counter(rolls).most_common(1)` Will give you a tuple of the most common result and # of rolls.

Comment: def func(l):
      m = statistics.mode(l)
      return (m, l.count(m))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
most = max(frequencies)
dice_roll_digit = frequencies.index(most)
```

`frequencies` is the list of all the frequencies you had collected.

Comment: That helped! Had to make one correction to get it to give the correct roll. Since indexing starts at 0:
most = max(frequencies)
dice_roll_digit = frequencies.index(most) + 1

But thank you :D